# How do I call set methods for each of my 3 data members to then display the values set by my set methods?

Tags: c++

I'm working on my Intro to C++ homework right now, and just got stuck on this last bit and would really appreciate some help.

**The directions for the homework are:**

*Ensure that the hour value is in the range 0 – 23; if it is not, set the hour to 1.*
*Ensure that the minute value is in the range 0 – 59; if it is not, set the minute to 0.*
*Ensure that the second value is in the range 0 – 59; if it is not, set the second to 0.*

*Provide a set function for each data member to validate the input going into the data member, using the values above.*

*Also, provide a get function for each data member to retrieve its value.*

*Provide a member function displayTime() that displays the hour, minute and second, each separated by a colon (Example: 3:45:29). displayTime should use the get functions to retrieve the data  in the data members.*

*Write a test program that demonstrates class Time’s capabilities as follows:*

*1.Prompt for hour, minute and second.*

*2.Create a Time object passing the values entered in response to the prompt(s) above.*

*3.Call displayTime to display the “Initial Time”.*

*4.Prompt again for hour, minute and second, and call the set methods for each of the 3 data members.*

*5.Call displayTime again to display the “Modified Time”.*

My current code for my project beginning with .cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class Time {
public:
//Time constructor
Time(int hour, int minute, int second)
{
    setTime(hour, minute, second);
}

void setTime(int input_hour, int input_minute, int input_second)
{
    setHour(input_hour);
    setMinute(input_minute);
    setSecond(input_second);
}

//set hour function
void setHour(int input_hour)
{
    if (input_hour >= 0 && input_hour < 24)
    {
        hour = input_hour;
    }
    else
        hour = 1;
}

//set minute function
void setMinute(int input_minute)
{
    if (input_minute >= 0 && input_minute < 60)
    {
        minute = input_minute;
    }
    else
        minute = 0;
}

//set second function
void setSecond(int input_second)
{
    if (input_second >= 0 && input_second < 60)
    {
        second = input_second;
    }
    else
        second = 0;
}


//get functions
int getHour()
{
    return hour;
}

int getMinute()
{
    return minute;
}

int getSecond()
{
    return second;
}

// display function
void displayTime()
{
    cout << "Time is " << hour << ":" << minute << ":" << second;
} 

//private data members
private:
    int hour;
    int minute;
    int second;
};
```

Now the .h file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Time.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{


    int hour, minute, second;

    cout << "Enter the hour: ";
    cin >> hour;

    cout << "Enter the minute: ";
    cin >> minute;

    cout << "Enter the second: ";
    cin >> second;

    Time printTime{ hour, minute, second };

    cout << "Time is " << printTime.getHour() << ":" << printTime.getMinute() << ":" << printTime.getSecond();

    cout << "\n\nEnter the hour: ";
    cin >> hour;

    cout << "Enter the minute: ";
    cin >> minute;

    cout << "Enter the second: ";
    cin >> second;

    cout << "Time is " << setTime();


    //the two lines to keep my debugger from crashing
    std::cin.ignore();
    std::cin.get();

}
```

I've gotten through 1-3 fine, but its steps 4 and 5 thats throwing me off. I'm not entirely sure what I'm supposed to be doing here. I understand what is supposed to happen. It's supposed to ask the user again to input data, and then its supposed to spit out 1:0:0 which is the "modified time" via the set functions (I think), but I'm not sure how to code it properly. I've got a feeling its something very simple, but again, I'm not sure what to do. "The third to the last line of cout << "Time is " << setTime(); obviously doesn't work. This is the first time I've ever learned how to program, so I'm not entirely sure what to do. Anyway, thank you for any and all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can understand, you just have to change the time using the set functions you have previously created. Something like this: (untested)

EDIT: there is `printTime.displayTime();`use it!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string> 

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int hour, minute, second;

    cout << "Enter the hour: ";
    cin >> hour;

    cout << "Enter the minute: ";
    cin >> minute;

    cout << "Enter the second: ";
    cin >> second;

    Time printTime{ hour, minute, second };

    printTime.displayTime();

    cout << "\n\nEnter the hour: ";
    cin >> hour;

    //Change the hour, minutes, and seconds - then display again
    printTime.setHour(hour);

    cout << "Enter the minute: ";
    cin >> minute;

    printTime.setMinute(hour);

    cout << "Enter the second: ";
    cin >> second;

    printTime.setSecond(hour);

    //Modified time
    printTime.displayTime();

}
```